# How do do multiple Unix Standard output redirections

Tags: unix, redirect, standards

If i were to write the standard output of a file i would do something like

```
python abcd.py > abcd.log
```

But if I do that i wouldn't be able to see the output of abcd.py, How would i change the above command so i can both see the ouput of abcd.py and also write the output to abcd.log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try use tee command

```
 python abcd.py | tee abcd.log
```

Comment: This seems to be printing extremely slow for some reason. Is this normal behavior

Comment: No, you might be hit by buffering artifacts but speed should be fine.

Answer (score 6):

Look at the tee command

```
python abcd.py | tee abcd.log
```